# Firebase Functions fail to validate AppCheck token, claims outdated even though just updated

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I just enabled AppCheck for my iOS App and Firebase Cloud Functions. In the Firebase Functions logs I get this message when I try to HTTPS call a Function:

```
Failed to validate AppCheck token. Error: Cannot validate AppCheck token. Please update Firebase Admin SDK to >= v9.8.0
at checkTokens (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:255:23)
at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:323:39)
at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:356:44
at cors (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
at /workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
at originCallback (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
at /workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
at optionsCallback (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
at corsMiddleware (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
at corsFunc (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:356:16)


Callable request verification failed: AppCheck token was rejected. {"verifications":{"app":"INVALID","auth":"VALID"}}
```

However, I've updated Admin SDK with the npm command and deployed my functions and entire firebase folder several times. [Admin SDK seems up to date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaGWt.png)

This is what the top of my Typescript file for Firebase Functions looks like:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import QuerySnapshot = admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot } from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore";
```

Is there something I'm not doing to make the updated Admin SDK take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that I didn't run the update command inside the functions subfolder but in my main firebase folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run that install command with the --save flag? You should see the updated version in your package.json if you did.  That may be what's missing.

[source](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/YKhKYgITca8)